# Telegram bot doesn't respond in group chats

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, botframework

I made a simple chatbot using [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) and integrated it with Telegram. 
He works fine whenever I message him privately but whenever I put him in a group with my friends, he doesn't reply, even when I mention him.
`/setjoingroups` is enabled, and so is `/setprivacy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you configured your bot on Telegram, did you make it an inline bot? It's been my experience that inline bots cannot participate in group chats, but can message privately. If not, please open a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) and we'll follow up there.

Comment: It is not inline, so I will open an issue.

Answer (score 5):

First make sure it is not caused by [Microsoft Bot itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/293). Then for all normal bots --

Always add a Telegram bot to a group via the bot's info window, instead of inviting the bot to a group via the group's info window.

It's a clear trap for beginners. I'm surprised that Telegram didn't note this in their documentation.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: I can confirm it works, while adding Telegram bots via the group's info window doesn't.

Comment: @xpt well, it does... for a while. Until it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond all other suggestions like turning off inline functions, setting privacy to disabled and allowing to participate in groups, I also made the bot an admin of my group. And now it processes all messages. That's what's worked for me.

Comment: you can also set this option via the botfather. works for me also. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I found that I just needed to add the bot as an 'admin' to the chat instead of just a normal member. The telegram bot must have admin privileges to access every message/image that the users of the group-chat send.